# Python reading TIF images using matplotlib, cv, and numpy reduces resolution

Tags: python, image, numpy, resolution, pixel

**This is my code in python to read TIF and save it as png file.**

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
#im.show()

from skimage import io  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import imageio
I = plt.imread('Shoes.TIF')

im=  Image.fromarray(I) 

print im.size

imageio.imsave('ShoesTest.png', I)


input_filename = "Shoes.TIF"


img =mpimg.imread(input_filename)

imgg=  Image.fromarray(img) 

print img

imgg.show()
```

However, when the new image is saved. I get an issue. When I try to check the resolution of the image in photoshop, I get this result.

> Original : 240 pixels / inch
>
> Saved Image : 96 pixels / inch

How do I save image in python that retains the resolution of the image? That is why I noticed visual changes in the images. Please help.

Comment: What is pixels/inch. just tell me how many pixels the images are. I ran this simple test with an image 6kX6k. and it looks fine (but I didn't use skimage)

Comment: Try to open your original image and saved image in photoshop and you will see the difference in the color. A bit lighter, and when can see that pixels / inch have reduced.